# slice removes object I want to work on

Tags: modeling

Josh Gambrell tutorial Beginners Hard Surface Modeling. On youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZNFu2VgQfJo at about the 23 minute. He created a round disc object, then a second cube object, intersecting it through the disc object. selecting the cube first then shift select the disc, using the bool tool he slices the objects (cntrl /), The disc now has a part sliced off of it that does not go away. He can then choose to work on the newly sliced part as a separate object. Every time I try to follow his lead I lose the sliced part or, in changing options of the bool tool, I loose the main disc object, never having both parts visible. I'm using Blender 3.0

Answer (score 0):

I tried the cube in the center of the disc and control/ (slice) worked as was describe in the tutorial. The bevel of the disc seemed to be the problem. Selecting the cube (intersecting the disc over the beveled edge of disc) then shift select the disc, I found that if I turn off the real time monitor selection in the bevel Modifier of the disc, then do a control/ (slice) the process worked. I lost the bevel modifier in doing this so I had to add the bevel modifier back to the objects. Seemed awkward but I don't know what other way I could make a object slice through a bevel edge of a second object and do it successfully.